# PXE boot stuck on "Start PXE over ipv4"

Tags: pxe-boot, wds

I have a server running Windows Server 2012 R2, on which I installed Windows Deployment Service and Microsoft Deployment Toolkit. I used MDT to capture an image and then I want to use PXE boot (powered by WDS) to deploy this image on computer.
The server is directly plugged to my client, and runs both DHCP server and PXE service point.

When I start my client PC, it displays:

```
>>Checking Media Presence......
>>Media Present......
>>Start PXE over IPV4.
```

Then nothing happens.
What can I have possibly done wrong? This is the first time I try this kind of things and despite reading a LOT of papers, I feel really confused.

Comment: Can you run a packet capture and see if the pxe client is generation any network traffic?

Comment: off course the client is generating network traffic `>>Start PXE over IPV4.`; but it does not get any answer from the DHCP server...

Comment: A test from a VM told me that indeed I did not receive response from DHCP server

Answer (score 1):

If DHCP and WDS is installed on the same server, one would need to right click on the server in the WDS management applet, select Properties | DHCP then tick the boxes "Do not listen on DHCP Ports" and "Configure DHCP options to indicate that this is also a PXE server"

If DHCP is installed after WDS, then option 60 would need to be manually configured.